# Select data for last 10 days

Tags: sql, date, datetime, group-by, mariadb

I want to implement SQL query for Bar chart which shows volumes per day for last 10 days. For example I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

I need to get this example result (grouped per day):

```
Date       | Amount| Number of transactions per day |
11-11-2018 | 30    | 3                              |
11-12-2018 | 230   | 13                             |
```

How I can implement this using MariaDB?

Comment: do you need the total amount per day - it would be better if you provider your expected output in table format

Comment: Yes - I need the total amount per day

Comment: This is a very broad question to which the answer is probably **"write a query"**. You should at least try something yourself before coming here. And then tell us your concrete problem, i.e. what you tried and where you are actually stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to chop off the time portion from date and group by this:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS Date, SUM(amount) AS Total_Amount, COUNT(*) AS Num_Transactions
FROM t
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

To restrict the results to last 10 days use the following where clause:

```
-- 10 days including today
WHERE created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 9 DAY
AND   created_at  < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY

-- 10 days excluding today
WHERE created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 10 DAY
AND   created_at  < CURRENT_DATE

-- 10 days from current time
WHERE created_at  > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 DAY
AND   created_at <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: One additional question. How I can limit the result for last 10 days?

Comment: See revised answer @peter

Answer (score 2):

You can try below

```
    select date(created_at) as cdate, sum(amount) as amount,count(id) as 
    nooftransaction
    from payment_transactions
    where date(created_at)>=date(now()- interval 10 day) and date(created_at)<date(now())
    group by date(created_at)
```

Comment: One additional question. How I can limit the result for last 10 days?

Comment: You need to add where condition @PeterPenzov - added in my answer you can check